# How to prevent form element from sending some fields we don't want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form element that contains about 5 fields which final query is going to create by processing values those fields. So I want to send only final query, not all of those, to the server. How can I exclude those fields from being submitted (using jQuery)?

```
<form action="abc/def.aspx" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="text" name="field3" />
    <input type="text" name="field4" />
    <input type="text" name="field5" />
    <input type="hidden" name="final" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Output of form submission looks like below:

```
abc/def.aspx?field1=val1&field2=val2&field3=val3&field4=val4&field5=val5&final=finalQuery
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery to do the submit currently, or is this a `<form method="get">`?

Comment: both, but i want an approach when browser JavaScript is turned off that work properly ;)

Comment: You have three options: (1) Set the `disabled` attributes to `true` for the fields. (2) Remove the fields' `name` attributes. (3) Remove the fields from the DOM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the element on submit.

On the onsubmit handler:

```
$(formElement).submit(function() {
    $(this.field1).remove(); //removing field 1 from query
    return true; //send
});
```

Disabling the form element also stops it from being entered into the query.(tested on Chrome)

```
$(formElement).submit(function() {
    this.field1.disabled = true;
    return true; //send
});
```

Comment: +1 - For a full version, just `$(':text', this).remove();` works, no need for a return either.

Comment: Alternatively, the script could just disable the inputs. I guess it doesn't really matter if it's a plain form submit, but if it were an Ajax form submission you might want the fields to be there still afterwards, and it's a little easier to just set "disabled" to false than to put the inputs back.

Comment: hm... using your approach disabled form fields even if form validation is not valid. how i can check if form validation is true then disable fields?

Comment: if form validation is in a function make it return a boolean and ask for that before doing the digitalFresh solution, for a more flexible solution maybe you should use something like jquery ajaxForm http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ it has options for validation/presubmit methods, callbacks and all kind of useful things

Answer (score 23):

Remove the name attribute on the fields you do not want submitted to the server.

```
<form action="abc/def.aspx" method="get">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="hidden" name="final" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

This is the simplest way to achieve what you want, and it works on all major browsers.

W3 spec talks about only submitting form values when name is present: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2

Comment: It works fine ;) !!! a good and straightforward solution without any JS code. It should be the good answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to handle the submit and then send the request yourself:

```
$(form).submit(function() {
    //do everything you need in here to get the final result
    var finalResult = alotoflogic();
    $.get("abc/def.aspx",final=finalResult, "callbackfunction", "responseType");
    return false;
});
```

that should do exactly what you want.
EDIT: as Alex pointed out this solution wouldnt send you to that page, just get the results if you need to go to the new page you can do:

```
$(form).submit(function() {
    //do everything you need in here to get the final result
    var finalResult = alotoflogic();
    window.location('abc/def.aspx?final='+finalResult);
    return false;
});
```

This way the browser is redirected to that page and only the final result is send.

Comment: A normal form submission will redirect the browser to the new location. As is, this would not do that - it would just fetch the results of the GET and then... who knows, depending on the call back function.

Comment: good point alex, just edited to add the non ajax solution ;) ty