# Make input text fields changeable and selectable (toggled with checkbox) 

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, checkbox

Please see my current html snippet is as below. I am trying to make html input fields changeable and selectable. So I can change the value of colors in input text field which is toggled with the corresponding checkbox. When the submit button is clicked, only the information of the selected color is submitted.
My current html displays the content correctly, but it will submit two colors information. Despite of only one checkbox is selected.

```
<form id="myForm">         
  <input type="checkbox" name="color1" value="blue_check" />  
  Color1: <input type="text" name="blue" value="120" /></br>  
  <input type="checkbox" name="color2" value="red_check" /> 
  Color2: <input type="text" name="red" value="160" /></br>   
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />    
</form>
```

or click on: http://jsfiddle.net/4xDFK/56/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm :checkbox').each(function() {
        $(this).next("input").attr('disabled',!$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});

$('#myForm :checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).next("input").attr('disabled',!$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

---

As you don't mention the use of JavaScript or a JS-framework, here is a suggestion to solve it with the pure html form and server-side evaluation:

1. Give the checkboxes a telling name, like "check_blue" + "check_red"
2. On the server side, only process the color if the corresponding checkbox has been selected

If you only want to so submit or allow filling of the inputs according to the checkbox state, you have to use JavaScript (and should probably have mentioned that in your question or at least as a tag).

Comment: Hi thanks Connum for your answer, I have added javaScript tag as you indicated.

Comment: Assuming the use of jQuery is okay, I updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks Connum for the quick reply, could you please further explain what does "$(this).next("input"). attr('disabled',$(this).is(':checked'));" exactly do? for applying this line,do I need to make some changes in my html snippet? please see: http://jsfiddle.net/4xDFK/56/  , thanks again.

Comment: As soon as one of the checkboxes changes, the next input field will be enabled or disabled according to the state of the checkbox. This snippet works with your markup without any changes, just try it out in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi Connum, just tried the snippet out, it goes opposite way: when color1 is checked, the value of color2 is submitted, any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove elements on submit , if related checkbox is not checked .

[how to prevent form from sending some fields we don't want to send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223365/how-to-prevent-form-from-sending-some-fields-we-dont-want-to-send)

Comment: thank you negadro for your reply, I did try your solution, it also worked cheers.

Answer (score 0):

All input values are submitted as you click hit the submit button. So what you need to do is to handle this on the server side. Give names to the checkboxes and check their values, google for "handling checkboxes in XXXX" where XXXX is your server side language.

```
<h1> Colors Information </h1>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice1" value="choice1"/>
  Color1: <input type="text" name="blue" value="120" /></br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice2" value="choice2"/>
  Color2: <input type="text" name="red" value="160" /></br>    
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

You can then check which checkboxes are checked, and accordingly see if you should put the corresponding text input fields into consideration.

Comment: thanks Mohamed I have just upgraded the checkbox linez as you indicated.