# Concatenate two form data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to concatenate two form sections from a form:
A radio button value and a drop down list value.

I want to submit the form and submit this concatenated value as a hidden value WITHOUT submitting the radio button and the dropdown list values.

What I've tried:

```
<script>
$('#lot1, #lotdet').bind('keypress blur', function() {

    $('#lot').val($('#lot1').val() + ' ' +
                             $('#lotdet').val();
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
Lot Change?:
Yes
<input id='lot1' name='lot1' type='radio'  value='Yes' onclick='showSelect();' />
No
<input id='lot1' name='lot1' type='radio'  value='No' onclick='hideSelect();' />

<select id='lotdet' class='hide'>
<option value=' '></option>
<option value='PGS'>PGS</option>
<option value='PGMIS'>PGMIS</option>
<option value='DTDMAS'>DTDMAS</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' id='lot' name='lot' value=$lot>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent form element from sending some fields we don't want?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223365/how-to-prevent-form-element-from-sending-some-fields-we-dont-want)

Comment: first of all, your form is wrong; the id's and the names of tags must be unique on a webpage;

Comment: As for the name, doesn't a group of radio buttons must have the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing `)` at the and of your line:

```
$('#lot').val($('#lot1').val() + ' ' +
                             $('#lotdet').val();
```

Should be:

`$('#lot').val($('#lot1').val() + ' ' + $('#lotdet').val());`

Beside: The **IDs** in your form should be **unique**

Created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/c7qQq/1/

Comment: How can I call that value in the hidden input value?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explained everything.