# Select a input box or select option box based on select type

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select option to select a particular type either 0 or 1 and an input box and another select box.

When the use selects 0, only the input box has to be displayed and when 1 the select box has to be displayed.

IMPORTANT: Again while submitting the form, only the box that is displayed has to be submitted. In my case both the values shown and hidden are submitted. Below is my code.

```
HTML
<form method="POST" action="test.php">

        <lable> Select Type </label>
            <select id="type" name="type">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select><br>

            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

            <select name="select" id="select"> 
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">

            </form>

Jquery:
$(function() {
                    $("#name").show();
                    $("#select").hide();

                    $('#type').change(function() {

                        if ($(this).val() === "0") {
                            $("#name").show();
                            $("#select").hide();
                        }
                        else if ($(this).val() === "1") {
                            $("#select").show();
                            $("#name").hide();
                        }

                    });
                });
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hidding an element will not stop it from being submitted

Comment: yes right. Is there any other way I could resolve the problem.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223365/how-to-prevent-form-element-from-sending-some-fields-we-dont-want