# How to get the browser to save the password even though it's not sending it to server

Tags: javascript, php, passwords, password-protection

**The situation :**

For security reasons, I never send the clear password to my server.
It is sha1ed client side and only the hash is sent to the server.
**edit : This is only part of my security** (I use also SSL, serverside hash, synchronised salts, ...) **Please dont make it a thread about security**

To do that, I have 2 inputs, first one one is visible and named "password" and another one is hidden named "sha1password".

When the user click the "login" button, a JS code sha1s the "input#password", put it into "input#sha1passord" and empties the "input#password" before sending a POST to the server.

This last step is to prevent the browser from saving the sha1 password. Because if you do that, the form will be filled with a 50 caracters password and the user would be annoyed.

**The problem :**

This works well but the browser dont save the passord as "input#password" is empty when sending the POST. Is there a way to allow the browser to save the password without sending it to the server ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent form element from sending some fields we don't want?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223365/how-to-prevent-form-element-from-sending-some-fields-we-dont-want)

Comment: This doesn't really add any security. If someone sniffs the connection, they'll get the sha1password, which they can then send to the server and get authenticated. Why don't you use SSL?

Comment: @Cerbrus It's not the same as that. He knows how to keep from sending the password to the server -- his question is how to get the browser to save the password in its keychain even though it's not sending it.

Comment: @Barmar : The question is not about security but about saving password into the browser.

Comment: I understand that. But the only reason why you're having trouble saving the password in the browser is because you're doing the silly thing with sha1password. You're doing that because you think it adds security, but it doesn't. So do the password the way everyone else does, and the browser will save it properly.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Barmar try working with banks and you'll have to learn about advanced security (i'm not playing bridge ;) ). Do you really think you know about that ? SSL is HUGELY not enough. Doing the way everyone do is the way everyone fails.

Comment: by the way I'm trying to rename the input containing the sha1 to "password" and make it visible the the browser thinks this is the actual password ans the actual input to autocomplete... (I'll answer is the solution works but it's still not)

Comment: It's strange that you want the browser to save the password -- I thought banks were the biggest users of `autocomplete=off`, because they don't like users saving passwords. Some of the financial institutions I use go to extreme lengths to design their login screens so that the browser won't save the password.

Comment: I give you that one ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Things to remember**

- Chrome dont save password if there is many password input
- Chrome check for many passwords is called after the page is loaded (even after jquery `$(function(){})` initialisation )
- To add another password input, just user a setTimeout function after 100 ms

**My solution**

Hi, I finally found how browsers works.
They don't like forms with many input type=password.

I renamed #sha1password to #password. In the first HTML page, there must me no other password input so I only echo the #password input ! This way, after loading the page, the browser sees a simple login form and enables the autocomplete feature (except IE but this one is stupid and I dont care with it... How microsoft people can always develop different softwares ?).

After page initialisation + 100ms timeout, I add a new input type=password called #clearPassword. I then copy the autocompleted value which is in the #password input. Then I hide the #password input using a width+height to 0px (display none make it unsent to the server).

When the user types a password in the #clearPassword input, I empty the #password input box. This will make the new typed password hashed, other wise #clearPassword stays with a hashed value.

When the user clicks LOGIN, **only if the #password box is empty** I sha1 the #clearPassword input and out the value in #clearPassword. If the #password is not empty, it is the autocompleted hashed value, this is OK.

And most important thing, before sending the form to the server, I detach the $clearPassword to prevent chrome from sending it to the server.

And you're done ;) chrome stores only a hash of the clear password