# Remove parameters before sending FORM POST

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I have page with one form made in C# on the page there are several HTML elements. On button click I am using jQuery and add hidden fields than I submit form to external domain. Now the issue is, that it is sending all the parameters which I don't need. Is there any way that I can send only parameter that I need. I want to send parameter only in body.

Is there way to clear form parameter before adding parameter

**jQuery Code**

```
$("#aspnetForm").attr("action", "www.example.com");
$("#aspnetForm").attr("method", "post");
var params = a.split('?')[1].split('&'); /*custom string with key/value and sperated with & */
$.each(params, function (index) {
    var paramsV = params[index].split('=');
    $("#aspnetForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="' + paramsV[0] + '" value="' + paramsV[1] + '" /> ');
});
$("#aspnetForm").submit();
```

There more than 50 HTML element are added dynamically in my form and at each load it have different id. So I cannot disable those element in Jquery or javascript

Comment: place the parameters you don't want outside form that's it

Comment: It is not possible as in C# we can have only 1 Form :(

Comment: if you use runat server yes it's not. then post using ajax

Comment: So mean to say create hidden HTML form and post it ?

Comment: you can do either ways as you are posting using javascript/jquery

Comment: Kindly can you give me example as answer. If it works I will mark it as answer

Comment: `<input id='excluded' type='text'><form><input id='included' type='text'></form>`

Comment: some of the elements are automatically added by C# I don't have control over it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent form element from sending some fields we don't want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223365/how-to-prevent-form-element-from-sending-some-fields-we-dont-want)

Comment: Thanks but it will not work in my case some of the element are added dynamically which I don't have control over it

Comment: There more than 50 HTML element are added dynamically in my form and at each load it have different id. So I cannot disable those element in Jquery or javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using SharePoint 2013, it have its own master page where it add lot of elements which I don't have control, so I cannot individually disable them.

What I did is I created dynamically form add required  parameter and then submit it.

Hope it can help somebody

```
$("#frm").remove(); /** remove extra frm before creating it **/
var frm = $('<form id="frm" action="' + _url + '" method="POST"></form>');
var params = a.split('?')[1].split('&'); /*custom string with key/value and sperated with & */
$.each(params, function (index) {
    var paramsV = params[index].split('=');
    frm.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + paramsV[0] + '" value="' + paramsV[1] + '" /> ');
});
frm.appendTo(document.body).submit();
```