# Create element by dom but not submit in php form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, innerhtml

I am creating some form fields through DOM inner HTML, but when i am submitting form that created fields are not submit.. please tell me the idea how i can handle this ...  i know why this is not showing ...

```
    var count = 7;
        $('#tbl_new_product tr:nth-last-child(2)').after(
            '<tr id="">' +
                '<td>' +
                     '<b class="text-success">' + $('#create_row_title_id').val() + '</b>' +
                     '<input type="hidden"  id="create_row_label_' + count + '" name="create_row_label_' + count + '" value="' + $('#create_row_title_id').val() + '">' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td class="center">' +
                    '<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">' +
                    '<input type="text" spellcheck="true" class="form-control" id="create_row_field_' + count + '" name="create_row_field_' + count + '" placeholder="' + $('#create_row_title_id').val() + '">' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
        );
```

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223365/how-to-prevent-form-element-from-sending-some-fields-we-dont-want). There is more than one solution to your issue suggested in the link.

Comment: but i want to submit form without using javascript

Comment: Are you sure the created fields are inside the form?

Comment: First, if you don't want javascript suggestions, don't tag this question with `javascript` and `jquery`. Second, based on your wording, I was under the impression you wanted to prevent certain fields from being submitted. Are you saying you want to submit the input elements you are dynamically adding? If so, like @Barmar asked, do you have this table in a form tag? You need a form tag to submit data. Otherwise you need to use javascript.

Comment: @AaronEveleth The tags are correct because he's using Javascript/jQuery to add the dynamic inputs, and he needs to know how to fix it so those inputs get submitted with the form.

Comment: @Barmar Fair point. Should've thought through that one.

Comment: Please provide your original HTML so we can see where this is being appended.